# Nativescript and Angular 2 navigation transition

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Could somebody tell me please how to use navigation transitions with nativescript and angular 2 application?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, navigation transitions are not yet implemented for NativeScript + Angular-2.
This feature is considered among with options like clearHistory and backStackVisible. You can track its development from the nativescript/angular repo or directly [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/202)

Comment: Is there any progress on this? the link refer to a 2.1 milestone.